# Is it possible to add some code in constructor runtime after clicking a button from other project?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, 3d, windows-forms-designer

I'm developing a simple application. I got two projects in the solution

```
1 WPF Custom Control Library
2 Windows Forms Application
```

I'm rendering some `3D visualization` on `WPF` and I got that embedded in the windows form as `UserControl`. So here is what I need to do in this project.
I've got 
`public void BuildObjectTest(InsertionPoint insertionPoint, Points point)` that visualize one object.
Anyway I want it multiple times from my windows `Form application` because I need to show several objects. I've got a textbox that when I write "barcode" I've got several object items in a `LIST` that show some label information and `buttons` `PREVIOUS` and `NEXT`. So I have to think in that way is it possible to add code in the constructor runtime or is there any other way I can do that?
This is how the constructor looks like:

```
public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InsertionPoints insertionPoint=new InsertionPoint(0,50,48);
            Points points=new Points(100,50,20);
            BuildObjectTest(insertionPoint,points);
            VisualizeBoxSides();
        }
```

Comment: Make `points` and `insertionPoint` [dependency properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview) of your usercontrol. Give them [propertychanged callbacks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.propertymetadata.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_PropertyMetadata__ctor_System_Windows_PropertyChangedCallback_). In their propertychanged callbacks, call BuidObjectTest() with the current values of the properties. Then, the winforms app can update these things. You can still call BuidObjectTest() in the constructor

Comment: Think of this as writing a control like a ComboBox or a TextBox: All of its features are exposed as properties or methods, so you can do what you like to them.

Comment: That's kinda cool but I want to call that method several times, with different objects not only once.

Comment: Read my first comment very, very carefully, several times. Do as I told you to do. Write the properties so that they call the method when the property values change. Set the properties as needed. I provided links to the documentation. If you have trouble implementing this, I can help you.

Comment: Quick work. What's the problem? Provide concrete detail and full text (not screenshots) of all error messages or exceptions. You can edit your question to add more code.

Comment: Please read the documenation I linked in my first comment, and consider doing as I suggested with the propertychanged callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update UI in WPF Form, I had to use:

```
userControl.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
   {
      userControl.BuildObjectTest(insertionPoint,points);
   });
```